# Не заходит в метод с аннотацией @PostConstruct (javax)

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Можно ли вызвать определенный метод инициализация сразу после вызова конструктора с помощью аннотаций из javax?

Я ставлю аннотацию Inject (`javax.inject.Inject`) над полем которое хочу инициализировать в методе с аннотацией @PostConstruct (`javax.annotation.PostConstruct`) сразу после вызова конструктора, но этот метод init не вызывается и падает NPE.

```
public class ClassChild extends ClassParent {
    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // getSomeValues() a method from parent
        someService = new SomeService(getSomeValues())
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я использую эти аннотации? В чем проблема? Как вызвать метод инит сразу после вызова конструктора ClassChild?

Comment: а как он может не вызываться и одновременно падать?

Comment: @Andrew NPE падает в другом месте, т.к. someService равен null

Comment: Тут надо понять, кто обрабатывает эти аннотации. У Вас Spring?

Comment: Нет, Spring не используется.  Я думал java под капотом сама вызывает метод с аннотацией @PostConstruct после вызова конструктора